# iPhone, is it possible to play a sound from the speakers while in a call?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, speaker

I would like to know from some iphone-Audio expert if there is a way to let a sound play through the line in of the microphone, or at least to play from the speaker (not the receiver) during a call.

I've tried different combinations of AVAudioSessionCategory with kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, but I've noticed that when the iphone is in a call, it plays sounds only through the receiver.

My best try for the moment is to pick the call in speaker mode, and put the AVSession sound in AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, but the result is too bad.

I repeat: i would like to play a sounds through the speaker while listening the call through the receiver.

I've used this in: http://www.pallaudio.com , the app that lets you lie at the phone!

Comment: For what I know there are no Apple Guidelines on this matter.

Comment: You're correct, but only in the sense there are really no "Apple Guidelines" at all that we, the public, know about. The approval process is incredibly opaque. But I think it's good bet that it's true. Caveat Programmer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, after long finding, the answer is simply: NO!

Comment: @DimitarMarinov : How?

Answer (score 1):

Very simply. It does it by playing the sound during a call initiated by ANOTHER device.
Fooled me too for a minute there...same deal as another app, called "Escape Pod".

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to what you're trying to achieve by doing so? Besides the fact that this could get your app rejected for non-standard behaviour (I'm sure Apple has some guidelines related to apps playing sounds during a call), this also seems like a sure-fire way to tick off a user (although maybe that's what you're trying to do).

Comment: A more ... erhm ... social version of the Pull My Finger app, perhaps?

Comment: Just what the App Store needs -- another fart-related app!

Comment: No, no fart app. Just a functionality I had on my nokia, that it's missing in the app store. When I'm done with it I'll tell you better.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://theamazingaudioengine.com/

It does have the capability to do this. From a user point of view though, I know sometimes Apple will throw a complaint about running sounds through the main speaker while the receiver is enabled at the same time too. Hopefully though, as long as you're not just planning on running fart sounds through the speaker, you should be ok.