# Is it possible to create a app that makes phone calls and play sounds when phone call begins and ends?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to do following task:

1. While on a conversation with a friend, (ie when call is received) play a sound from my phone so the other person on the other phone can hear it. (Call began notice)
2. When the call is ended, play hung up sound like we used to have in our Landline telephone. (Call ended notice).

So, I was thinking of doing this creating my own phone call apps like iphone has by default. But the question is this be feasible? I have gone through several posts related to this topics and it seems me possible.

Can anyone please tell me how much is it feasible? Most posts says after call ended, I have no control over my app, but some says there is possibility so play sound using AVAudioPlayer's delegate.

Please inform me whether it is technically feasible or not? If I started it now but is not possible for app to get approval from apple in appstore then I will be totally ruined. So, before getting started, I need some help.

Comment: did you achieve what you was trying to do? I also need to play sound over call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you can't. Apple doesn't allow you to do anything related to phone calls, other than start a call. The only way is if you do some kind of over-the-internet call, like a skype phone. But that won't be like a normal phone call.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo for quick response. But there are some apps that would make phone call. So all those apps are just for initiating calls ?

Comment: Correct. Once you initiate the call, iOS puts your application in the background and that's the end of it. You can only hang up the call from the phone app, there's no API to control that.