# is it possible to play system sound through phone app?

Tags: android, iphone

Is there a way to play sound through the iPhone or android phone app. Can I play a sound so the other party can hear a song. Is there API access to the telephone stack.

Comment: Android- you can play the sound over the loudspeakers and hope its picked up.  No way to send it directly to the call.  Also, phone calls use a codec that's optimized for small size and vocals-  it won't transmit music well.

Comment: According to this, the answer is no at least for iOS:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962395/is-it-possible-to-create-a-app-that-makes-phone-calls-and-play-sounds-when-phone/

Comment: Yes I realize it won't be good quality, but at least I wish there was a way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not allow you to modify the outgoing audio stream during a call. The best you can do is to play whatever you want to over the loudspeaker and hope the microphone picks it up.

Apple doesn't allow you to do anything except initiate calls on iOS, so it isn't possible on that either.

Comment: I can just add that some Android devices' hardware platforms supports playback of audio in the voice call uplink. But since there's no API for in Android there's no way for apps to make use of the functionality. I'm unsure if we'll ever see such an API being added officially, since there are very few use-cases for this functionality if you exclude prank apps (an answering machine app would be the main one, I guess).